# Excel Mac VBA editor - can't add references

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm trying to add references to my VBA project.  Everything online indicates that I should get a list of possible references I can add, however all I can find is this list of references I already have - as in the screenshot.

Does anyone know how to add in the references I am looking for:

Microsoft Internet Controls

Microsoft HTML Object Library

[image]

Comment: Those are Active-x controls which are not supported on the Mac. You will have to use Web queries to fetch live data.

Comment: @braX thanks!  I'm not sure web queries can do what I need so I'll find another way.