# Exporting UTF-8 CSV with double quotes from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-csv

[According to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/troubleshoot/excel/export-text-file-with-comma-quote) you can just use their Visual Basic macro to export columns from a table to a CSV with double quotes:

```
Sub QuoteCommaExport()
   ' Dimension all variables.
   Dim DestFile As String
   Dim FileNum As Integer
   Dim ColumnCount As Long
   Dim RowCount As Long

   ' Prompt user for destination file name.
   DestFile = InputBox("Enter the destination filename" _
      & Chr(10) & "(with complete path):", "Quote-Comma Exporter")

   ' Obtain next free file handle number.
   FileNum = FreeFile()

  ' Turn error checking off.
   On Error Resume Next

   ' Attempt to open destination file for output.
   Open DestFile For Output As #FileNum

   ' If an error occurs report it and end.
   If Err <> 0 Then
      MsgBox "Cannot open filename " & DestFile
      End
   End If

   ' Turn error checking on.
   On Error GoTo 0

   ' Loop for each row in selection.
   For RowCount = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count

   ' Loop for each column in selection.
      For ColumnCount = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count

        ' Write current cell's text to file with quotation marks.
         Print #FileNum, """" & Selection.Cells(RowCount, _
            ColumnCount).Text & """";

         ' Check if cell is in last column.
         If ColumnCount = Selection.Columns.Count Then
            ' If so, then write a blank line.
            Print #FileNum,
         Else
            ' Otherwise, write a comma.
            Print #FileNum, ",";
         End If
      ' Start next iteration of ColumnCount loop.
      Next ColumnCount
   ' Start next iteration of RowCount loop.
   Next RowCount

   ' Close destination file.
   Close #FileNum
End Sub
```

However the final outputted file does not seem to use the UTF-8 charset.

How can the above Visual Basic be edited so that the resultant CSV is encoded using UTF-8?

At the moment, the outputted CSV file has an unusual encoding. Examining the CSV in a HEX editor shows that a character like `ä` is stored as a single byte (`8A`). When this CSV is opened in Excel it correctly shows `ä`, but in everything else it shows `�`.

I don't know what character encoding Excel is using, as this character should be typically stored as `E4` when using a single byte, or `C3 A4` in UTF-8.

Comment: It's not a fix, so just a comment, but Excel is using a **codepage**. That is, basic ASCII only supports 128 characters, so it only needs 7 bits. You can use the 8th bit in each byte to map additional characters. But which ones? Codepages are references for how to interpret byte values of 128 and above.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thank you for explaining that. I was wondering!

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn The question now is figuring out what codepage they're using. `ä` = `8A`. `‡` = `E0`. `Ë` = `E8`.

Comment: @ChuckLeButt That is not really the question. The `ä` and `‡` are not there, you see them because the program with which you are viewing the file is showing them to you. Some other program could show something else. The `Print` operator uses the system codepage for non-Unicode programs that you set in the Windows settings.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next way. It places selection in an array (for faster iteration) bo build the necessary string and write is (as UTF-8) using `"ADODB.stream"`:

```
Sub QuoteCommaExport_()
   Dim DestFile As String
   ' Prompt user for destination file name.
   'DestFile = InputBox("Enter the destination filename" _
       & Chr(10) & "(with complete path):", "Quote-Comma Exporter")
   
   DestFile = ThisWorkbook.path & "\testFile.csv"
   If Dir(left(DestFile, InStrRev(DestFile, "\")), vbDirectory) = "" Then _
         MsgBox "The folder where to save the csv file does not exist...": Exit Sub
   Dim arr, i As Long, j As Long, strLine As String, strTxt As String
   
   If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Exit Sub 'if something else than a Range is selected...
   
   arr = Selection.Value2

   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            strLine = strLine & ",""" & arr(i, j) & """"
        Next j
        If i = 1 Then
            strTxt = Mid(strLine, 2) & vbCrLf
        Else
            strTxt = strTxt & Mid(strLine, 2) & vbCrLf
        End If
        strLine = ""
   Next i
   strTxt = left(strTxt, Len(strTxt) - 1)

  WriteUTF8NoBOM strTxt, DestFile
End Sub
Sub WriteUTF8NoBOM(strTxt As String, fileName As String)
 Dim UTFStream As Object, BinaryStream As Object
 With CreateObject("ADODB.stream")
    .Type = 2
    .Mode = 3
    .Charset = "UTF-8"
    .LineSeparator = -1
    .Open
    .WriteText strTxt, 1
    .Position = 3 'skip BOM
    Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("adodb.stream")
    BinaryStream.Type = 1
    BinaryStream.Mode = 3
    BinaryStream.Open
    'Strips BOM (first 3 bytes)
    .CopyTo BinaryStream
    .flush
    .Close
 End With
 BinaryStream.SaveToFile fileName, 2
 BinaryStream.flush
 BinaryStream.Close
End Sub
```

The above code saves the csv file in the folder where the workbook keeping the code exists, with the name "testFile.csv" You may use whatever name you want, defined in the way you try, or in any other way...

I posted a (more complicated) method to save as CSV UTF-8 without BOM. If UTF-8 with BOM is good enough, please use the next (simpler) writing `Sub`:

```
Sub writeUTF8BOM(strTxt As String, fileName As String)
   Dim objStream As Object
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 2
        .Charset = "UTF-8"
        .Open
        .WriteText strTxt, 1
        .SaveToFile fileName, 2
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

You can test what type of UTF encoding the resulted file uses, opening it in Notepad++ and click 'Encoding' menu. You will see there the encoding type...

**Edited again**:
The next version will save selection as CSV (UTF-8) directly:

```
Sub QuoteCommaExport()
   Dim DestFile As String
   ' Prompt user for destination file name.
   'DestFile = InputBox("Enter the destination filename" _
       & Chr(10) & "(with complete path):", "Quote-Comma Exporter")
   
   DestFile = ThisWorkbook.path & "\testFile.csv"
   If Dir(left(DestFile, InStrRev(DestFile, "\")), vbDirectory) = "" Then _
         MsgBox "The folder where to save the csv file does not exist...": Exit Sub
   Dim arr, i As Long, j As Long
   
   If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Exit Sub 'if something else than a Range is selected...
   
   arr = Selection.Value2

   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            arr(i, j) = """" & arr(i, j) & """"
        Next j
   Next i

   ActiveSheet.Copy 'this linw creates a new workbook with the content of the active sheet
   Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
   Set wb = ActiveWorkbook: Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
   ws.cells.Clear
   ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Value2 = arr 'drop the processed array content
   wb.saveas fileName:=DestFile, FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8, Local:=False
   wb.Close False
End Sub
```

What is wired, if you do not process the range (adding double quotes), it is correctly saved, any non ASCII character being saved as it should. But if you add the double quotes (placing a break point before `wb.Cloe False` line) you will see the correct (number of) double quotes. If you open the csv file in Notepad+++ the strings are between triple double quotes...

If you try opening it in Excel (as text, filtering txt, rtf, csv) and the 'Text qualifier' is `"` then it is open as it should... If choose there 'none' the file will be open with each string surrounded by triple double quotes.

Trying to open it using `Open x For Input` does not correctly read the non ASCII characters, so the double quotes cannot be placed after saving or deleting the exces, as I was supposing to be possible (in my comment)...

Now, an ugly solution (but working) is to open the saved csv file in Notepad, press `Ctrl + H` to bring `Find and Replace` window, write `"""` in the top left box and `"` in the one below it, then press `Replace All` followed by saving the file.

Now, I do not even know if in MacOS Notepad exists (most probably, not)... Maybe a similar application having the option to mass replace.

If by chance it exists, I can squeeze my brain and I think I can update the code to automatically open the file in Notepad, find the `Replace` option in the `Edit` menu (using API) and launch the appropriate window. I will try this scenario only for the sake of seeing it working, if you confirm the Notepad application existence. I am sure that until this step I can do it without more complications. Finding the handles of the `Replace` window, automatically write the strings to be used and programmatically press the necessary button, may be more complicated...

**Final Edit**(I hope...):

Please test the next version, which (theoretically) should work in MacOS, too. It uses a function to convert a Byte array (of the string to be saved) into a byte array that can be written to create a UTF8 Encoded file. Then, another function writes the converted byte array into a file:

```
Sub ExportSelectionAsUTF8CSV()
   Dim DestFile As String, strLine As String, strTxt As String
   ' Prompt user for destination file name.
   'DestFile = InputBox("Enter the destination filename" _
       & Chr(10) & "(with complete path):", "Quote-Comma Exporter")
   
   DestFile = ThisWorkbook.path & "\testFile.csv"
   If Dir(left(DestFile, InStrRev(DestFile, "\")), vbDirectory) = "" Then _
         MsgBox "The folder where to save the csv file does not exist...": Exit Sub
   Dim arr, i As Long, j As Long
   
   If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Exit Sub 'if something else than a Range is selected...
   If Selection.cells.count < 2 Then Exit Sub 'It does not treat the case of a single cell...
   
   arr = Selection.Value2
   
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            strLine = strLine & ",""" & arr(i, j) & """"
        Next j
        If i = 1 Then
            strTxt = Mid(strLine, 2) & vbCrLf
        Else
            strTxt = strTxt & Mid(strLine, 2) & vbCrLf
        End If
        strLine = ""
   Next i
   strTxt = left(strTxt, Len(strTxt) - 1)
   
   Dim b() As Byte
   b = strTxt 'place the string in a bytes array
   
   WriteByteArrToFile DestFile, UTF8Encode(b) 'encode UTF-8 and write to the file...
 End Sub

Private Function UTF8Encode(b() As Byte) As Byte()
    Dim b1, b2, b3 As Byte         ' UTF8 encoded bytes
    Dim u1, u2 As Byte             ' Unicode input bytes
    Dim out As New Collection      ' Collection to build output array
    Dim i, j As Integer, unicode As Long

    If UBound(b) <= 0 Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    For i = 0 To UBound(b) Step 2
        u1 = b(i)
        u2 = b(i + 1)
        unicode = u2 * 256 + u1

        If unicode < &H80 Then
            ' Boils down to ASCII, one byte UTF-8
            out.Add (u1)
        ElseIf unicode < &H800 Then
            ' Two byte UTF-8
            ' Code path not tested
            b1 = &H80 Or (&H3F And u1)
            b2 = &HC0 Or (Int(u1 / 64)) Or ((&H7 And u2) * 4)
            out.Add (b2) ' Add most significant byte first
            out.Add (b1)
        ElseIf unicode < &H10000 Then
            ' Three byte UTF-8
            ' Thai chars are in this range
            b1 = &H80 Or (&H3F And u1)
            b2 = &H80 Or (Int(u1 / 64)) Or ((&HF And u2) * 4)
            b3 = &HE0 Or (Int(u2 / 16))
            out.Add (b3) ' Add most significant byte first
            out.Add (b2)
            out.Add (b1)
        Else
            Stop ' This case wont arise as VBA strings are 2 byte. If stopped here, something really strange happened...
        End If
    Next

    Dim outBytes() As Byte
    ReDim outBytes(1 To out.count)
    For j = 1 To out.count
        outBytes(j) = CByte(out.Item(j))
    Next
    UTF8Encode = outBytes
End Function

Function WriteByteArrToFile(filePath As String, fileB() As Byte)
    Dim fileNo As Integer: fileNo = FreeFile
     
    If Dir(filePath) <> "" Then Kill filePath   
    Open filePath For Binary Access Write As #fileNo
        Put #fileNo, 1, fileB
    Close #fileNo
End Function
```

I am not the 'creator' of the encoding function. I have it form some years and I do not know where from I downloaded. I did not need it, but it looked interesting and only tested that time...

Please, send some feedback to confirm that it works in MacOS as it should, too.

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you. Unfortunately I'm getting an error: `Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object`. It appears to be related to the line: `With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")`

Comment: I'm wondering if it's related to me being on MacOS

Comment: @Chuck Le Butt Ups... Please try adding the next reference: `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library` Most probably 2,8. I do not use MAC, but I did not hear about such a missing on your version... To do it, from VBE, click on `Tools` - `References`, check in in Available References and press `OK`.

Comment: Apparently you can't use ActiveX on the Mac :-( You need to use "web queries" instead (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64579825/excel-mac-vba-editor-cant-add-references). This is an endless rabbit hole of a problem!

Comment: Driving now....

Comment: @Chuck Le Butt I do not use MacOS and I read now about this weakness... Is MacOS VBA able to deal with VBScript objects? Does VBScript work in MacOS. VBScript is able to save a string in Unicode, but not UTF-8. It is able to do it in UTF-16. Would that be convenient for you?

Comment: I think the only thing it can't do is ActiveX (because of security issues). I think UTF-16 would work because then I could manually convert it to UTF-8. Do you think it's possible? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Chuck Le Butt Since I do  not know too much about the fact that MacOS is able to use VBScript, I am waiting an OK from you on this issue... I know how to write some text in UTF-8, **but using `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`**. Is your environment able to accept such an object? Or, between the small list of accepted references, is there something similar to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'? Are you able to use a `Dictionary`, for instance? Or, if VBScript can run on your computer, to prepare a version in VBScript. Which to search for Excel open session and do all the job from there.

Comment: Unfortunately from the little research I've done, it seems that VBScript is a Windows only thing :( Thanks again for trying so hard!

Comment: @Chuck Le In such a situation, I am am not sure I can help... It is a way to save a workbook directly as UTF-8, but when I tried it after adding double quotes on each cell, the resulted csv was UTF-8 but with three double quotes on each side, instead only one. Then tried without quotes and it returned without any such quotes. Not availability now, but when I will find some time  I will also post such a version. If I will make it returning (directly) the desired format, it will be OK. If not, we may open it (as text) and process in terms of adding the necessary double quotes (I think)... :)

Comment: @Chuck Le I made a second **Edit** and place a version able to save directly from Excel. But, with the above mentioned problem of the triple double quotes on the text sides...

Comment: @Chuck Le I took your question as a challenge... It must be a way, using standard VBA! Now, I have an idea. I remember, I have from many years a function able to convert a Unicode Byte array into a byte array that can be written into a UTF8 Encoded file. I think I will solve the problem on this scenario. Theoretically, I only need to find the function in discussion (I am not its father...) in my computer archive, and use it for the string already created in the previous versions and make a function to binary write a file... If not in my computer, I will search on internet, knowing what I need.

Comment: Thanks again for your tireless help! You've been wonderful. I have found a workaround for my specific situation: I found the encoding it was using (`MacRoman`). Once I reloaded the file with the correct encoding I was able to convert to UTF-8. HOWEVER the ability to export CSV files with double quotes in UTF-8 format must be a very common request!

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean... Where could you set the 'encoding type (`MacRoman`)? And changing that, could you save as UTF-8 and no triple double quotes have been saved? Anyhow, please test the last version I supplied and send some feedback. It should be very fast and nothing than running the code needed...

Comment: Any decent text editor (like Visual Studio Code). I opened the exported CSV file in that, set the encoding to MacRoman. Sure enough the characters appeared correctly once this was done. I then converted the file to UTF8 in the same app and voila! Done. Sorry for not seeing your latest edit until now. There are other fires I'm trying to put out, but I will endeavour to test your code ASAP! Thanks again